# Detect browser window "Maximized" / "Minimized "with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, maximize-window

When the user clicks the "Maximized"/"Restore" or "Minimized" buttons of the browser window, is there a way to keep track of these events with JavaScript? Are there any appropriate event or property to use?

I want that when the user clicks the "Maximized" button at the top-right of the window, the webpage should stretch to a specific width and when the browser is in the resizable mode, the webpage is resizable.

Please can someone help me in this? I don't mind either JavaScript or jQuery.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but jQuery *is* JavaScript.

Comment: Yes I know that, but I didn't want to write a long sentence that explains how jquery derives from javascript and that I don't mind whether the code should be long using javascript or short using jquery, just like I'm doing right now...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is a layout that resizes when the browser is resized but only up to a maximum width.

If that's the case you can either do it in CSS or in JavaScript.

Imagining that your content is in an element like:

```
<div class="container"> -content here- </div>
```

My preferred option would be to use CSS as follows:

```
.container{
    max-width: 1200px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

If you need to support IE6 (which doesn't support max-width) you can try using an expression in the IE6 CSS:

```
.container{
    width:expression(document.body.clientWidth > 1200 ? "1200px" : "100%" ); /*IE6*/
}
```

If you want to use JavaScript: you could just resize your elements in the window's resize event:

```
$(window).bind('resize', function() {
    // resize $('.container').width() based on $(window).width()
});
```

You could initially trigger that logic using

```
$(window).trigger('resize');
```

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, there isn't a sure fire way to detect if a browser window is minimized, but if you want to detect for the maximized state, try:

```js
function CheckWindow() {

  var A = screen.availWidth;
  var AA = window.outerWidth;

  var B = screen.availHeight;
  var BB = window.outerHeight;
  
  if (A == AA && B == BB) {
  
    // Window is maximized

  }
   
  else {
   
    // Window is not maximized or in full screen
    
   }

}
```

```html
<body onresize = "CheckWindow();" onload = "CheckWindow();">
```

This takes into consideration the browser toolbar, and works for me in Chrome and Edge on my PC.  I have not tried it in the other browsers or on mobile devices. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, it is relatively easy to do in modern browsers such as **Edge**, **Chrome** and **Opera**. IE and Firefox need more cumbersome workarounds. FF also can't show minimized state.

Feel free to check it in your browser via snippet below. Compatibility is limited by its support of [window.outerWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/outerWidth) and [window.screenX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/screenX) functions (IE9+, Opera 12, Chrome 1), earlier browsers still can handle it, but it takes major work giving minor usability.

The check is intentionally performed in timed-out **onCheck()** function, 3 seconds after the button is clicked. This allows you to click the button, minimize browser, and then restore it to see the result. This works *at any zoom level*. Note that in fullscreen mode it shows normal state. If your device/OS supports split screen (Windows 7+ etc), we can check it as well (little bonus). Please kindly test it in your browser, and leave some comments below.

```js
function onCheck() {
  if (isMaximized()) window.alert('MAXIMIZED');
  else if (isMinimized()) window.alert('MINIMIZED');
  else if (isSplitScreen()) window.alert('SPLIT SCREEN');
  else window.alert('NORMAL');
}

function isMaximized() {
  return (window.screenX === 0) && (window.screenY === 0) &&
  (window.outerWidth === window.screen.availWidth) &&
  (window.outerHeight === window.screen.availHeight);
}

function isMinimized() {
  return (window.screenX < -window.screen.availWidth) &&
  (window.screenY < -window.screen.availHeight);
}

function isSplitScreen() {
  return (window.screenY === 0) &&
  ((window.screenX === 0) || (window.screenX === window.outerWidth)) &&
  (window.outerWidth === window.screen.availWidth / 2) &&
  (window.outerHeight === window.screen.availHeight);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="window.setTimeout(onCheck,3000)">Check</button>
<p>Click the button and minimize, maximize or split (Win7+) the window.<br>
The result pops up in 3 seconds.</p>
```