# Detecting window maximize in javascript

Tags: javascript, onresize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detect browser window Maximized/Minimized with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371973/detect-browser-window-maximized-minimized-with-javascript)

Is it possible to detect the maximize window of a borwserwindow in javascript.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371973/detect-browser-window-maximized-minimized-with-javascript

Comment: Can you show the function that the event trigger?

Comment: I was actualy wrong about the resize function not being called yet still I would like to know if you can detect the maximize button being clicked. Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if am correct check this code

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

function Minimize()
{
window.innerWidth = 100;
window.innerHeight = 100;
window.screenX = screen.width;
window.screenY = screen.height;
alwaysLowered = true;
}

function Maximize()
{
window.innerWidth = screen.width;
window.innerHeight = screen.height;
window.screenX = 0;
window.screenY = 0;
alwaysLowered = false;
}
</SCRIPT>

<A HREF="javascript:onClick=Minimize()">Minimize</A>
<A HREF="javascript:onClick=Maximize()">Maximize</A>
```

you can also give on load to give maximize on loading....

Comment: the op wants to know when the maximize event is fired not fire it himself/herself

Comment: This is not what I wanted but thanks.

Comment: What I wanted is an event to catch so I can call a function when maximize is called.

Comment: Considering that the question that this is supposedly a duplicate of doesn't answer this question can we reopen this? No one has answered how, or if its even possible, to detect when the maximize button has been pressed. Why don't we try answering questions instead of being stack overflow  question policy nazis.