# Bootstrap One Page Navigation Fluid site minimization problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This page works fine when using a full window and dynamically changes its hight and width to the device screen resolution using a responsive bootstrap layout. My problem is when the page gets minimized it looses it's containers and as you can see it messes it up completely.

Could someone please advise as to what is the issue.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    .intro-section {
  /* height: 100%; */ < Remove the 100% height
  padding-top: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #fff;
}

.about-section {
  /* height: 100%; */ < Remove the 100% height
  padding-top: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #eee;
}

.services-section {
  /* height: 100%; */ < Remove the 100% height
  padding-top: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #fff;
}
```

After removing those heights , it should display it normaly, on any size , even  when u minimize it :)

Comment: Cheers buddy, Just out of interest do you think it would be possible to use javascript to detect when the screen is minimized and dynamically change that css property.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371973/detect-browser-window-maximized-minimized-with-javascript 

Maybe this is what you want